# MySQL prefix timestamp to a inserted value

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have table 'worktickets':

```
    wt_id    problem        created           follow_up1           follow_up2      updated
    1          LCM       2017-08-24          visited client                          2017-08-25 08:15
```

The 'updated' attribute is set to 'current timestamp on update'. Is it possible to prefix this to what is inserted into the follow_up1 or follow_up2 attributes?

For example:
INSERT into worktickets (followup_2) VALUES ('visited client again');
I would get:

```
wt_id    problem        created           follow_up1           follow_up2                                updated
1          LCM       2017-08-24          visited client    2017-08-25 08:20: visited client again        2017-08-25 08:20
```

How would one adjust the attributes for follow_up1 and follow_up2 to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your example `INSERT` statement looks a little thin, more like an `UPDATE`, and would probably not result in all those other columns being populated.

I would actually recommend *not* storing the timestamp as a prefix in other columns.  The reason for this is simple: It takes up space, denormalizes your data conceptually, and is not necessary.  Instead, I recommend just building the format you want at the time you query, e.g.

```
SELECT CONCAT(updated, ': ', follow_up2) AS follow_up2
FROM worktickets
```

That being said, if you really want to prefix the update time, you could do via an `INSERT ... SELECT`, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO worktickets (follow_up2, ...)
SELECT CONCAT(updated, ': visited client again'), ...
FROM dual;
```

Comment: This makes sense. The column 'updated' changes for each and every update right? If I create a update_1 which is linked to follow_up1, is it possible to link them? i.e. upated_1 does not update again when follow_up2 is updated, only update_2 is updated, and update_1 remains as when follow_up1 was updated.

Comment: Yes, each timestamp would correspond to the time of insert/update, because you specified what the value is.  Not sure about the rest of your question.

Comment: I'll create a separate question.